# Why am I getting this writing access violation error?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure why this is happening. Updated my original post to add in the suggestions made thank you everyone for your help!

The issue function was made by my professor. The function I am making is the `board()` function.

**MY FUNCTION**

```cpp
TourBus& TourBus::board()
{
    char passName[40];
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Boarding " << busSizeNumber << " Passengers: " << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < busSizeNumber; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << "/4- Passenger Name: ";
        cin.getline(passName, 40,'\n');
        ticket->issue(passName);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

**MY PROFESSOR'S FUNCTION**

```cpp
TourTicket& TourTicket::issue(const char* passengerName) {
    if (passengerName && passengerName[0]) {
        copyName(passengerName);
        m_ticketNumber = next_ticketNumber++;
    }
    return *this;
}
void TourTicket::copyName(const char* str) {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 40 && str[i]; m_name[i] = str[i], i++);
        m_name[i] = 0;
    }
```

This is a picture of the instructions for this function:

[image]

this is the picture of the error
[the variables i am watching are all holding the string correctly however its just not copying it and throwing that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhGJt.png)

Comment: What memory is `passName` using when you call `getline`?

Comment: Perhaps of note - in [an earlier version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74019046/getting-access-violation-writing-location-error) the line was `char* passName = nullptr;`

Answer (score 2):

In this line, the method declares a pointer but doesn't initialize it to point to anything:

```
 char* passName;
```

... and then in this line you call `getline()` and pass in the uninitialized pointer as an argument:

```
 cin.getline(passName, 20,'\n');
```

`getline()` will try to write some text into the buffer that `passName` is pointing to... but `passName` is uninitialized, so it is not pointing to any well-defined region of memory.  Hence, the attempt to dereference it invokes undefined behavior, and you get a write-access error.

I think you'd get a result more in line with what you wanted if you changed the `passName` declaration to something like this:

```
char passName[20];  // allocates 20 bytes of stack space to hold chars in
```

Comment: thank you that helped alot! However in this copy function it says that there is an error reading the string but the name i am passing to it is going through void TourTicket::copyName(const char* str) {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 40 && str[i]; m_name[i] = str[i], i++);
        m_name[i] = 0;
    }

Comment: @samanthaadasilvaa your `passName` variable is allocated to hold only 20 `char`s max, but that loop in `copyName()` is trying to read up to 40 `char`s from `passName`.

Comment: I changed it 40 and still the same thing

Comment: @samanthaadasilvaa Then there has to be other problems with the code than you have shown yet. Please show the actual errors, and provide a [mcve] to reproduce them.

Comment: i updated my original post to demonstrate the error